# saving / restoring the NVRAM

Tags: macos, terminal, nvram

I need to find a reliable way to save and restore the contents of NVRAM.

Would this be correct?

Preservation

```
nvram -x -p > ~/nvram.xml
```

Recovery:

```
sudo nvram -x -f ~/nvram.xml
```

Comment: In reading the man page for `nvram(8)`, the `-f filename` _option_ states, "_Set firmware variables from a text file. The file must be a list of "name value" statements. The first space on each line is taken to be the separator between "name" and "value". If the last character of a line is \, the value extends to the next line._" and by my interpretation an XML file does not conform to those specifications, whereas a straight dump (just using the `-p` _option_) to a file does. I'd read the man page (in Terminal `man nvram`). Since I haven't tested this, I'm posting as a comment vs. an answer.

Comment: Also note it states "_Changes to NVRAM variables are only saved by clean restart or shutdown._", so keep that in mind when restoring.